# jquery Increasing score after matching random numbers

Tags: jquery, if-statement, increment

I've been trying to figure out on the how to do an increment each time the button is clicked after the random numbers matches, or doesn't match.

Basically, if the numbers matched, a counter for matched will go up. Same goes for mismatched numbers.

But currently, the counter will only go up once and only once.

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var a;
    var b;
    display();
    displayInt();

    function displayInt(){
        var disInt;
        disInt = setInterval(display, 2000);
    }    

    function display() {

        a = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
        $("#number1").html(a);
        b = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
        $("#number2").html(b);    
    }

    function addScore(){
        var correct;
        var wrong; 
        correct=0;
        wrong=0;

        if (a == b){
            correct++;
            $("#correctScore").html(correct);

        }else{

            wrong++;
            $("#wrongScore").html(wrong);    
        }
    }

    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {

        a = $("#number2").html();
        b = $("#number1").html();
        addScore();

    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `correct` is local in the function `addScore`. It is increased every time, but it is also set to 0 every time. You need to place `correct` and also `wrong` outside that function.

```
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 0;

function addScore(){
    if (a == b){
        correct++;
        $("#correctScore").html(correct);
    }else{
        wrong++;
        $("#wrongScore").html(wrong);    
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a;
    var b;
    var correct = 0;
    var wrong = 0; 

    display();
    displayInt();

    function displayInt() {
        var disInt;
        disInt = setInterval(display, 2000);
    }    

    function display() {
        a = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
        $("#number1").html(a);
        b = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
        $("#number2").html(b);    
    }

    function addScore() {

        if (a == b) {
            correct++;
            $("#correctScore").html(correct);

        } else {
            wrong++;
            $("#wrongScore").html(wrong);    
        }
    }

    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        a = $("#number2").html();
        b = $("#number1").html();
        addScore();

    });    
});
```